# the code is giving error during compilation, please explain

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int values[10];
    int a = 10;

    values = &a;
    printf ("the value is = %i.\n\n", *values);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is written just for experimenting on pointers, I have just started learning it.
My question is that if  the name of the array is a pointer then why cant we copy some other variable's address into it.

The error that it gave was "assignment to expression with array type"

please explain it in simple way.

Comment: Contrary to what many people will tell you, arrays are not pointers. They cannot be assigned to.

Comment: "giving error"?  *What* error?

Comment: `int values[10`] is an array. You cannot assign another variable's value to it.

Comment: You want `int * values` not `int values[10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays cannot be assigned to.  You can store values into array elements and you can store array addresses into pointers, but arrays themselves cannot appear on the left side of an assignment operator.

You can change `values` to a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *values;
    int a = 10;

    values = &a;
    printf ("the value is = %i.\n\n", *values);

    return 0;
}
```

or you can store `a` into `values[0]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int values[10];
    int a = 10;

    values[0] = a;
    printf ("the value is = %i.\n\n", *values);

    return 0;
}
```

think of arrays as parking lots:

- You can store a car into a parking spot (array element)
- You can write the lot number on a piece of paper (lot *pointer*, you can retrieve the car by giving that to the operator).
- You cannot *store* a parking lot into another parking lot, they are not moveable.

Comment: so we can say that the array name values is a pointer which is a constant pointer. am i right?

Comment: No, an array name is not a pointer. In the parking analogy, the piece of paper **is** the pointer. The name of the spot, or of the lot is the **value** of the pointer, an address. The array name is the address of the array, it can be used as a pointer **value**, and that's exactly what happens when you use an array in an expression (except as an argument to `sizeof`): the array *decays* to a pointer to its first entry.

Answer (score 1):

Array designators are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not use an array designator in the left side of the assignment expression.

Thus the compiler issues an error for this statement

```
 int values[10];

 int a = 10;

 values = &a;
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```